# div value to jquery or php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

1.In my js file i have this:

```
var updateInterval = setInterval(function() {
 $('#thealert').load('alertprice.php');
},1*1000);
```

In my php file i SELECT the latest price from MYSQL database for example 453.33

In html it shows at time 14:00:01 :

```
<div id="thealert">453.33</div>
```

Then at time  14:00:02 :

```
<div id="thealert">463.33</div>
```

How do i get the updated value in a jquery or php variable so i can use it for an alert script ?

I want always to have in variable:

```
$latestprice = "463.33";
```

Or what ever latest price is at current time.

I want to store the updated value inside the div in a php variable or jquery or javascript variable to be used by other scripts ,if **div** value changes then **$latestprice** should change also.

Update:$latestprice needs to go in here:

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var mychange = '';
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
       $.get('alertprice.php').success(function(resp){
          $('#thealert').html(resp);
          mychange = resp;
       })
    },1*1000)


    $( "#myHigh" ).keyup(function(e) {

    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

    if ( key == 8){}else{


    nHigh = $( "#myHigh" ).val();
    $('#myHigh').append(nHigh);

    if (nHigh <= mychange ) {
    document.getElementById('play').play();
    }else
    {
    document.getElementById('play').pause();
                return false;
    }}
    });


    $( "#myLow" ).keyup(function() {
    nLow = $( "#myLow" ).val();
    if (nLow >= mychange

) {
    document.getElementById('play').play();
    }else
    {
    document.getElementById('play').pause();
    }
    })


    $( '#cleara' ).click(function() {
            $('input:text').val('');
        });






    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ajax for request:

```
var change = '';
var interval = setInterval(function(){
   $.get('alertprice.php').success(function(resp){
      $('#thealert').html(resp);
      change = resp;
   })
},1*1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var price;
var updateInterval = setInterval(function() {
   $('#thealert').load('alertprice.php', function(){
    price = $('#thealert').html();
   });

},1*1000);
```

This way, you gonna store the `$('#thealert')` inner HTML into a variable

Answer (score -1):

I think You should use class instead of id, like this

```
<div class="thealert"><?php echo $price; ?></div>
```

Comment: What difference could it makes ?